# Viewpager with Youtube Player API

Tags: android, android-viewpager, youtubeplayer

I have used `ViewPager`. And In some of the items, I have used `Youtube Player Fragment.`

I used PageTranformers from [this Android Dev Page](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is,

If I used **`DepthPageTranformer`**,

when I move to that page(which has youtube fragment) , I am getting warning

> W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to
>   unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is
>   obscured by android.widget.RelativeLayout{28896be5 V.E..... ........
>   39420,0-39960,850}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the
>   distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the
>   YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 510..

But it works if I didn't use any transformer or with ZoomPageTranformer.

I debugged the code with custom ViewPager to check which view is

`android.widget.RelativeLayout{28896be5 V.E..... ........ 39420,0-39960,850}`

It is the previous page of the page which has Youtube Player Fragment .

I tried all the solutions like,

1. **removing padding** and margins
2. setting **background as black**
3. setting all the view's visibility  which **overlaps as View.GONE**

Everything works fine if I don't use DepthPageTranformer.

## EDIT

As we know, Viewpager's OFFSCREEN_PAGES=1 by default. So the next and previous page will be in cache. Consider, If player view is in 5th page, If I move to 7th page and move back to 5th page , then video is playing. It clearly says that the **`"previous page of video page overlays"`** . Is there any way to refresh this page or remove previous page from OFFSCREEN_PAGES LIST.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it looks like the animation coveres YouTube player with some other view, which is not allowed by the YouTube player. So basically you can't use this animation

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I accept your point, But I am trying to make app like "inshorts" , in that app , they have used DepthPageTranformer. And it works fine. That's why I am thinking that, there will be a solution for it

Comment: It will be easier if you share the code in `DepthPageTranformer` and anything related so we can see how you translate, show/hide the pages

Comment: @TamHuynh please check , I edited the post

Comment: @JyotiJK I try your `Transformer` on my ViewPager with `YouTubePlayerView` on each item and it works fine. Each video can be played without being covered. I doubt that the `RecyclerView` mentioned in the error is not the previous item in `ViewPager`. Try to add id to some of the `RecyclerView`, the error usually show the view's id too

Comment: @TamHuynh I am not using recyclerview. Just **Viewpager without fragments**. And I am using videoview in some of the pages

Comment: My bad, I mean `RelativeLayout` instead of `RecyclerView`. The `RelativeLayout` that mentioned in the Youtube error message said it cover your view. Try to put `android:id` in some of `RelativeLayout` in the app to see if its id shown up in the error message

Comment: @TamHuynh thanks let me check it

Comment: @TamHuynh I checked, It is the previous page relative layout id. I am inflating different layouts based on the type in `instantiateItem()` . is Inflating different layout  a problem???? But it works fine without the tranformer

Comment: I don't think inflating different layout is the problem. Now it's become harder to debug without seeing how it's covered. Some options you can do for now: Change the `RelativeLayout` background color, disable any alpha setting so you can see where it is after the transformation. Use `Android Studio` Tools>Layout Inspector or `Stetho` to inspect your layout and see how the views are positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this interface *YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener* Activity or Fragment. It overrides below method,

```
override fun onFullscreen(isFullScreen: Boolean) {
    if (isFullScreen)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    else
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

**Why is this happening?**

When playing youtube videos using **YouTubePlayerFragment** or **YouTubePlayerView**, we need to hide the **Status Bar** because of no more views will not be added above **YouTubePlayerFragment** or **YouTubePlayerView**.

I had also this issue and found a solution.

Just try this one.